# Is RestSharp thread safe?

Tags: c#, rest, thread-safety, restsharp

After a few failed attempts to post data to a website via REST, I decided to look into using a library for doing that.

RestSharp seemed the obvious option. However, after a bit of digging, I've found [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restsharp/X8JPtcfnSlo).

I couldn't find evidence of any updates regarding this problem neither on the RestSharp google group nor on [GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp).

The issue was reported before the last release, but again I couldn't find out if the issue had been fixed.

Does anyone know if the issue has been fixed?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try, or otherwise just use one instance per thread, as described in the linked Google group page.

Comment: unfortunately, at work, I can't just give something a try because of time being an issue ;) can you point me to the right topic in the group please?

Comment: Quote from Adam Ralph in topic: "If I change 
to creating a new RestClient in each thread, everything works 
perfectly." [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/restsharp/X8JPtcfnSlo/Fmj5Pvhqm0wJ)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the answer is no. RestClient is not thread safe, at least until this issue is closed:

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/951